# How to use Stack Overflow API in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following URL:

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions?page=1&pagesize=30&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

When I type this URL in my browser's address bar, it gives me a JSON response, which I need in PHP. I tried using cURL to fetch it (see below code), but it didn't work — no response is printed on the page.

```
function get_json($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $resultCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($resultCode == 200) {
        return json_decode($data);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$json = get_json('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions?page=1&pagesize=30&
  key=VVq3kJHSjQ*7qgpiRaVoLA%28%28&site=stackoverflow');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json);
```

How can I fetch this URL and convert it into a PHP array the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last I checked, **all** responses from the API were gzip'd:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
  , CURLOPT_HEADER => 0
  , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
  , CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip'
));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data);
var_dump(json_decode($data));
```

Setting `CURLOPT_ENCODING` enables automatic un gzip'ing of the response, in addition to sending an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in the http request, although sending that header isn't strictly required for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

To return an array, use the second parameter in [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and set it to `true`.

```
if ($resultCode == 200) {
    return json_decode($data, true);
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.stackexchange.com/.............."));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
```