# How to get questions using StackOverflow API V 2.2 in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, stackexchange-api

I am working on a project and want to get questions from stack overflow using Stack Overflow API. I searched the way how to achieve the same here:

1. [how to get a list of questions from stackoverflow API based on search query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433422/how-to-get-a-list-of-questions-from-stackoverflow-api-based-on-search-query)
2. [Getting null as response from Stack Overflow API with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825188/stack-overflow-api-access-with-php)
3. [How to use Stack Overflow API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172112/how-to-use-stack-overflow-api-in-php)

But I found nothing useful as they are old techniques. They are using old Stack Overflow API versions.

While going through stackapps I read that to achieve this task I have to register my app. I have registered an app on www.stackapps.com. and I got an APP ID and its SECRET KEY.

I visited here https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication to know how to get data from stack API V 2.2. They have given useful links to get data using Stack Overflow API V 2.0 using authentication via OAuth 2.0

It says ask for a request from user and then get "code" etc. I got stuck here. What should be the process in order to move forward using PHP.

My app should do this:

Let input link be : https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

I get data of this page in any of the two form either HTML or JSON.

Can it be done without OAuth. If not, then please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have registered your application.

Go to Manage your applications from here https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth

Enable Client side flow within App settings.

Now as you want to create Desktop application, following are steps:

1. First you need to get Access Token by redirecting user to this link:
   https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=[YOUR_APP_ID]&scope=private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
2. You (as a user) will approve the request made by the application. Then you will be redirected to another link in which there will be an access_token.
3. Grab the access token from there and put it in this link :

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=descsort=activity&site=stackoverflow&key=[YOUR_APP_KEY]&access_token=[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]&filter=withbody

This will be your ready API.

Get content using:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('https' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
$json_array = file_get_contents("YOUR_API_URL", false, $context);
$data = json_decode(gzdecode($json_array),true);
print_r($data); // Show your file data
```

The data you will get is in JSON and is compressed (in GZIP from). So we decompressed it and then decoded JSON.

This should work. It worked for me. :)